# Is there a way to know the very instant that sshd becomes available on a remote box?

Tags: linux, ssh, cloud

Lots of cloud providers (AWS, GCE, etc) allow you to start up a machine instance, and then start billing you immediately. It can take anywhere from minutes to tens of minutes for the server to come up though. Is there a way to know (ideally from a script) the instant that sshd becomes available on the server?

Comment: Why? This is the perfect time to go refill your coffee.

Comment: I think I'm missing the reason for wanting to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
until nmap example.com -p 22 | grep -q open ; do sleep 1 ; done
```